# Carga arbitrária de entidade especializada no Java/Hibernate, a partir de associações

Tags: java, hibernate

Então, seguinte ... eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de classes que tratada pelo Hibernate:

( **<|-** é um símbolo para denotar herança, **1 --*** é um simbolo para denotar uma associação um pra muitos)

```
[Pessoa] <|- [Medico]

[Pessoa] <|- [Professor]

[Pessoa] 1 -- * [Contato] * -- 1 [TipoDeContato]
```

(Para efeito de reforço, na entidade Contato há um atributo que é do tipo Pessoa. Assim, qualquer instancia de Medico, ou Professor, pode possuir uma relação com nenhuma ou várias instâncias de Contato)

Tenho persistido os seguintes objetos (só para teste) (uma tabela/classe):

```
Pessoa: { id: 1, nome: "José Maria" }

Medico: { id: 1, crm: "0001" }

Professor: { id: 1, matricula: "20" }

TipoDeContato: { id: 2 , tipo: "email" }

Contato: { id: 2, pessoa: Pessoa { id: 1 }, tipoDeContato: TipoDeContato { id: 2}, contato: "jose@jose" }
```

**Problema**: quando carrego um contato, e acesso o conteudo do atributo pessoa definido aí (Contato), imaginei que ele deveria retornar uma instancia de Pessoa. Só que não! Carrega arbitrariamente, ao que me parece, uma instancia de Medico. Pq ele carrega uma instancia de Médico? Pq não carrega uma instancia de Professor, ao invés?!

trace do SQL gerado para a consulta pelo hibernate:

```
select * from
    public.contato this_ 
inner join
    public.pessoa pessoa2_ 
        on this_.pessoa_id=pessoa2_.id 
left outer join
    public.medico medico_1_ 
        on pessoa2_.id=medico_1_.id 
left outer join
    public.professor professor_1_ 
        on pessoa2_.id=professor_1_.id 
inner join
    public.tipodecontato tipodecont3_
```

Uso java hibernate apenas. é um exercício que estou fazendo para um outro trabalho. Quando fui avaliar o comportamento de herança, deparei-me com isso. Estranho! Ajudas?

Observando o SQL do Hibernate para a consulta, vejo que ele dá um join em todo mundo: Pessoa, Contato, TipoDeContato e Medico, Professor. Como?!!

ps.: compreendo que muito possivelmente possam argumentar que médico e paciente são interfaces e não entidades. ok, mas não há casos em que isso possa ser avaliado como sendo sim entidades especializadas?!

mais,

```
public class Pessoa { public Long id; public String nome; }

public class Medico extends Pessoa { public String crm; }

public class Professor extends Pessoa { public String matricula; }

public class TipoDeContato { public Long id; public String tipo; }

public class Contato { public Long id; public Pessoa pessoa; public TipoDeContato tipoDeContato; public String contato; }
```

Comment: qual o tipo de strategy SINGLE_TABLE ou JOINED ?

Comment: @DilneiCunha , é isso que vc quer saber? @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)

Comment: @DilneiCunha em cada uma das entidades que ponho na árvore de especialização eu defino na declaração da classe @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED). É isso? No mais, no banco, eu tenho uma tabela por classe

Comment: Eu imaginei, já que este é o comportamento default do tipo JOINED, e esses joins são o preço a se pagar por usar herança, mas o problema maior é que precisa de um discriminator, qual o seu driver do banco?